# ReactLeafletDriftMarker not drifting

Tags: react-leaflet

Good day,

I have a map with markers that move every 3 seconds to a new location, using ReactLeafletDriftMarker. I cannot, unfortunately, share my code since it is confidential.

My issue is that the markers do not **drift**, they just **jump/appear** in the next location.

Does anyone know what causes this to happen?

I can share this snippet:

```
{Object.entries(latlng).map(([key, value]) => {
          return (
            <ReactLeafletDriftMarker
              position={value}
              duration={4000}
              keepAtCenter={false}
              icon={markerIcon}
            >
            </ReactLeafletDriftMarker>
          );
        })}
```

It shows how (around) 400 points move on a map.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please create a demo or provide the code with the minimum code required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake. I assigned a key to the container, so it re-rendered every time the markers changed position values.